# Efeito "chuva de imagens" em CSS3, JQuery ou JavaScript. Como fazer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

O que tenho:

-Uma div com classe "background-bg", cuja imagem preenche toda a tela.

```html
<div class"background-bg"></div>
```

O que quero fazer:

-Criar um efeito "de chuva/ neve"(tipo caindo) usando outras 20 pequenas imagens(120x120).

Resultado esperado:

1-Quando a página for carregada, a imagem de fundo( classe "background-bg") cobrirá toda a tela;

```css
.background-bg{
  background-image: url("img/background-bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
.background-bg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
}
```

2-Após 5 segundos, uma "chuva" de pequenas imagens deverá acontecer de modo infinito.

Pesquisando na web eu encontrei efeitos de neve [aqui](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Creating-Snow-Falling-Effect-with-jQuery-snowfall-Plugin.html), [aqui](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Realistic-Raindrops-Effect-with-Canvas-Rainyday-js.html), [aqui](http://www.thesoftwareguy.in/create-snowfall-effect-using-jquery/) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333422/create-random-falling-object-in-jquery).

Eu quero algo bem parecido,com 20 imagens e não com apenas 1.

Alguém pode me dizer como consigo fazer ?

Comment: A demo do  primeiro link usa um plugin que permite mais uma imagem. Dá uma olhada no arquivo javascript dele. Dá pra criar um array de imagens que farão o efeito. `graphics: ['images/flake2.png', 'images/flake.png']`

Comment: Ok..vou dá uma olhada.